# Searching for data in DynamoDB or using a search service

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to know the pros and cons of trying to search for data (basically full text search on a limited set of fields).

My data is currently in DynamoDB, and I realize that is not well suited to full-text search. Are there ways of doing a full-text search in DynamoDB? What are the pros and cons of doing that?

I can also use a Search cluster (like ElasticSearch). Any reasons that you would not go with a search cluster?

Are there other ways to do a full-text search? Other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamodb is best suited for key value Insert and Retrieval.

It does not support search functionality, if you are trying to do a scan with some condition that will be O(n) and it will be very costly since you are consuming lots of read capacity.

Now coming to options

1. If use case is not full text search and only key value match, you can try to come up with [composites key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/), but it will have drawbacks like

   a. Can not change the schema afterwards and may require huge effort if you need to search on a new field.

   b. Designing these kind of key is tricky considering that few keys will always be hot, and may result into hot partition.
2. Ideal solution is to use elastic-search or solr indexing. You can have a lambda function listening to dynamodb stream, doing transformation and putting data in elasticsearch. But it will have limitations like

   a. Elasticsearch cluster is [costly](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/pricing/).